# "Invalid argument false with type bool." when flutter application starts

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I run my application, I get the following output.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on PRO 6 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Waiting for PRO 6 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:35519/lTvS-OPVNiM=/ws
Syncing files to device PRO 6...
I/flutter (19084): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.kinton.application/app_flutter'
I/flutter (19084): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.kinton.application/app_flutter'
I/flutter (19084): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.kinton.application/app_flutter'
I/flutter (19084): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.kinton.application/app_flutter'
I/flutter (19084): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.kinton.application/app_flutter'
I/flutter (19084): *** WARNING ***
I/flutter (19084): 
I/flutter (19084): Invalid argument false with type bool.
I/flutter (19084): Only num, String and Uint8List are supported. See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_common/blob/master/sqflite_common/doc/supported_types.md for details
I/flutter (19084): 
I/flutter (19084): This will throw an exception in the future. For now it is displayed once per type.
I/flutter (19084): 
I/flutter (19084):     
D/ContentCapture(19084): updateCollectionAppInfoImpl time=6
```

Here's what the flutter doctor says.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Linux, locale ru_RU.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Do I need to do something about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is with your SQL table and not your flutter code. This is most likely happening cause you're using a false instead of a boolean type in your table. I might be wrong as I don't use sqflite but check this first if it helps

Comment: This is it, thanks! I am using a custom class for database instances and forgot to convert values from integer to boolean.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: To clarify the answer: SQLite doesn't support boolean types explicitly, using 0/1 integers instead. To fix my database-updating/inserting code I changed any reference to a boolean to (myBool?1:0)